# Error in merge code in update

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update few values in a particular column. I make a copy of that column and then update the values in new column. but my merge code makes all the values null where no change are required. Can anyone help me

```
UPDATE L04_A_AVOX_DATA
   SET NIK_Regulatory_Classifciation = Regulatory_Classification;

MERGE INTO L04_A_AVOX_DATA n
     USING (SELECT NIK_SEQ_AVOX, new_value
              FROM (SELECT *
                      FROM L04_A_AVOX_DATA
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN
                           (SELECT old_value, new_value
                              FROM TRANSFORMATION_DATA_ALL
                             WHERE     column_identifier =
                                          'Regulatory_Classification'
                                   AND Source_identifier = 'Avox')
                              ON Regulatory_Classification = old_value)) o
        ON (n.NIK_SEQ_AVOX = o.NIK_SEQ_AVOX)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET NIK_Regulatory_Classifciation = o.new_value;
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. Looking at this query I'd say you don't even need MERGE + your MERGE can fail if there are not unique PWC_SEQ_AVOX in your view.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery

```
"SELECT * FROM L04_A_AVOX_DATA LEFT JOIN <doesn't matter> ON <doesn't matter>"
```

always return at least the whole L04_A_AVOX_DATA. That's why when you are making a MERGE all the rows are updated (there is always a match for each row)

Moreover, the merge may fail if a view used in USING clause have dublicate o.NIK_SEQ_AVOX (MERGE is deterministic)